# How to execute two functions (close and save) in AJAX success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax call. If you see the success part, there are actually 2 fucntions. One is the popup message to display that the file is saved. Other is the window.close().

```
$.ajax({
    url: perlURL,
    data: form_data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'post',
    cache: false,
    datatype: "script",
    success: function(result) {
        var offset = $("#jqxgrid").offset();
        $("#popupWindow2").jqxWindow({
            position: {
                x: parseInt(offset.left) + 360,
                y: parseInt(offset.top) + 160
            }
        });
        $("#popupWindow2").jqxWindow('show');
        window.close();


        error: function(data) {
            alert('Error');
        }

    });
});
```

I want to ensure that the popup message is displayed. As soon as it displays the popup message, the webpage at the back part of popup message should close. Thats y i have used window.close() method.

I tried interchanging the sequence of function but it only closes the window. Pop up alert doesnt display. How to ensure that i display the popup and close the window at backside.

Comment: You don't have a real popup, you have a modal/dialog, which is just an element, so of course it disappears when the window closes.

Comment: @aadeneo- right, is there any way to ensure it works ?

Comment: You can display the popup and after e.g. 3 second close the window. Is this appropriate?

Comment: @Ashwin but.. it does work. it does exactly what it should be doing. you need to specify what you wish for it to do instead. Currently it shows the message, and then immediately closes the window, before the browser renderer runs to render the message.

Comment: You can have an "ok" button on the dialog - which when clicked will close everything - which seems to me more like what you're aiming for, as this is a modal behavior

Comment: @adeneo- Is there any other way to ensure it works. I mean display pop up and then close the window ? 
can we use some other way instead of window.close() ?

Comment: @Ashwin the part that is unclear is the "and then close the window". When is "and then"? after a period of time? after the user clicks ok? what?

Comment: Try adding $("#popupWindow2").jqxWindow('close'); instead of the window.close()

Comment: @KevinB- User saves file. Pop up shows. as soon as pop up shows, the window should be closed.

Comment: @Ashwin but... that's exactly what is happening currently. that obviously isn't what you want hence why you asked this question.

Comment: `as soon as pop up shows` - how long? a millisecond?

Comment: @KevinB- i dont see a popup. the window closes nevertheless. even if i put the sequence back forth in success, it wil direclty close the window.

Comment: @Ashwin - do you see the popup if you remove the `window.close` statement?

Comment: @guymograbi- yes, i do see the pop up otherwise.

Comment: @Ashwin - this means the code works you're just not writing what you mean. When you add the `window.close` everything happens too fast for your eye to see the dialog. the dialog has to appear at least 1/12 of a second for the eye to see it before the window closes - however the way you wrote it, it is less than that.

Comment: @guymograbi- will putting a delay to the window.close() function work ?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @guymograbi for clearing this simple concept. I am able to add interval and then execute these 2 functions.

Here is that code, if anyone wants to see.

```
success: function (result) {
                            var offset = \$("#jqxgrid").offset();
                            $("#popupWindow2").jqxWindow({
                            position: {
                                        x: parseInt(offset.left) +360,
                                        y: parseInt(offset.top) +160
                            }
                            });
                            \$("#popupWindow2").jqxWindow('show');

                            setTimeout(function(){window.close(); },2000);
                            },
```